# <pre> tag doesn't work anymore in VSCode with JDK 17

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javadoc

Up until recently, I always used the `<pre>` tag in javadoc to format code and it always worked, but since I switched to JDK 17 a few days ago, anything inside `<pre>` tags seems to be ignored by VSCode.
For example:

```java
/**
 * The following code should be formatted correctly:
 * <pre>
 * Code
 * </pre>
 */
public class Test {
...
```

renders as

[image: Content inside pre tags not showing up at all]

How can I make it so it shows up properly again?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried, and it's a little difference between java17 and java14. Different CSS styles caused it. You can take F12 to check the HTML sources.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "you can take F12 to check html sources"? The default keybinding for F12 is go to definition / references

Comment: @WeinSim Sorry for that, I mean you can take F12 in the browser to check the CSS style.